# How to represent meta data in JSON

Tags: node.js, json, metadata, jsonschema, json-api

> Note: this is a NodeJs app

I have the following JSON object that stores questions and answers:

```
{
    "id": "SOME_GUID",
    "questions": {
        "page-1": {
            // ... JSON schema for page 1.
        },
        "page-2": {
            // ... JSON schema for page 2.
        }
    },
    "answers": {
        "page-1": {
            "page-1-question-1": "something"
        },
        "page-2": {
            "page-2-question-1": true,
            "page-2-question-2": "foo"
        },
    }

}
```

Is there a benefit of representing the data in a specific way over another? I would naturally opt for a simple key/value pair notation (shown below) as it seems to fit the bill here. But I have seen the "array notation" (shown below) in the wild (in projects written in Java)

key/value pair notation (what I would naturally use):

```
{
    "meta": {
        "createdData": "some date",
        "modifiedData": "some date",
        "referenceNumber": "some reference number",
        "type": "some type code"
    }
}
```

or

"array" notation

```
{
    "meta": [
        {
            "key": "createdDate",
            "value": "some date"
        },
        {
            "key": "modifiedData",
            "value": "some date"
        },
        {
            "key": "referenceNumber",
            "value": "some reference number"
        },
        {
            "key": "type",
            "value": "some type code"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: What language/framework are you working in?  That could have a great impact on the answers you receive.  For instance, in JS, the object approach would give you properties that you can directly reference.  In C# the object approach would require a hash & lookup, but would still be (generally) faster than array iteration.  Additionally, the size of your data may come into play.

Comment: This is written in Node. It will generally be a small dataset.

Comment: You have tagged this question as belonging to [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/). This one is very clear about how you should represent a resource. Was this by accident or did you ask for arguments why you should follow that specification?

Comment: Ah sorry. that was an accident. I am using JSON:API within this project, but this specific file does not need to adhere to those standards.

Answer (score 1):

> I would naturally opt for a simple key/value pair notation

In that case, you might wish to consider the
[JSON Extended Structural Schema](https://bitbucket.org/pkoppstein/jess) language 
(JESS) and associated tools, which include a schema inference engine
and verification checker.

The idea basically is to use the inference engine to get a draft schema that exactly mirrors the input; modify it as needed,
e.g. to to override some inferences or to define more complex constraints; and then
use the derived schema with the verification checker.

The [inference engine](https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/a5abb4ebef3b0f72a6ed) requires valid JSON as input, so I've tweaked the sample given, as shown below.  Given this as input,
the schema inference engine produces:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "questions": {
    "page-1": {
      "page1 schema": {}
    },
    "page-2": {
      "page2 schema": {}
    }
  },
  "answers": {
    "page-1": {
      "page-1-question-1": "string"
    },
    "page-2": {
      "page-2-question-1": "boolean",
      "page-2-question-2": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

### Caveats

1. The inference engine and checker currently require [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to run.  There is a node.js wrapper for jq (e.g. `yarn add node-jq`), which might help.
2. JESS is relatively new.  The JESS Language is stable but there are some finer points that are subject to change.
3. I am the author of JESS.

### Sample JSON Input

```
{
  "id": "SOME_GUID",
  "questions": {
    "page-1": {
      "page1 schema": {}
    },
    "page-2": {
      "page2 schema": {}
    }
  },
  "answers": {
    "page-1": {
      "page-1-question-1": "something"
    },
    "page-2": {
      "page-2-question-1": true,
      "page-2-question-2": "foo"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "characteristics": {
        "organism": {
            "name": "",
            "accession": "",
            "ref": ""
        },
        "organism_variant": {
            "name": "",
            "accession": "",
            "ref": ""
        },
        "organism_part": {
            "name": "",
            "accession": "",
            "ref": ""
        }
    }

}
```

Reference Link : https://2isa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other/json-metadata.html

Comment: Your answer is missing any argument why this format should be preferred over others.